# Strange build error on Travis, local tests in tox work

Tags: python, django, travis-ci, tox

I have a strange error on Travis, the builds of https://travis-ci.org/edoburu/django-fluent-blogs fail in Django 1.7 and lower with:

```
from django.utils.six import python_2_unicode_compatible

ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible'
```

This is importable for every Django version the build tests against, and somehow only works for Django 1.8. Running tests locally with tox works.

Any idea's why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [django.utils.encoding](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.encoding):

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
```

Comment: Thanks, it turns out this compatibility rule was added in some Django point release:

`# For backwards compatibility. (originally in Django, then added to six 1.9)
python_2_unicode_compatible = six.python_2_unicode_compatible`